# python, client sends data to server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, flask, client-server

It's a small web demo. My server side is written by python-3(flask), both front-end and back-end work fine. But now I want to write another client python code and try to send data(say, 'foobar') to my server.

Here's part of my server side code.

```py
@app.route('\', methods=['POST', 'GET']
def show_index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I am not sure how to write the client code and how to modify my server code.

Comment: [The documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/) contains all the information you need to be able to upload files to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal server and client using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package for the HTTP client.

### server.py

The server simply pulls the value of `data` from the Flask request objects `form` attribute which is populated by data from the POST request, and returns it as an HTTP 200 response.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_index():
    data = request.form.get("data")
    return data, 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### client.py

The client makes a POST request to the Flask server sending the data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

```
import requests

response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", data={"data": "foobar"})
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```